# how can I save the color then .obj file ， using PCL

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

pcl version 1.9.1
I read .txt file，and create PointXYZRGB ，set x、y、z and rgb，like this：

```
#include <pcl/io/io.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/io/obj_io.h>
#include <pcl/PolygonMesh.h>
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/io/vtk_lib_io.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/cloud_viewer.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace pcl;
int main()
{
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
std::string s;
while (cin >> s) {
    ifstream input(s);
    std::string line;
    std::int32_t number = 0;
    while (getline(input, line))
    {
        if (number % 10000 == 0) {
            cout << "重置点数"<<number<<endl;
            cloud->points.resize(number + 10100);
        }
        stringstream sstr(line);
        string token;
        int32_t tokennumber = 0;
        while (getline(sstr, token, ','))
        {

            if (tokennumber == 0) {
                cloud->points[number].x = atof(token.c_str());
            }
            else if (tokennumber == 1) {
                cloud->points[number].y = atof(token.c_str());
            }
            else if (tokennumber == 2) {
                cloud->points[number].z = atof(token.c_str());
            }
            else if (tokennumber == 3) {
                int32_t num = std::stoi(token.substr(1), NULL, 16);
                int32_t red = num >> 16 & 0xFF;
                int32_t green = num >> 8 & 0xFF;
                int32_t blue = num & 0xFF;
                cloud->points[number].r = red;
                cloud->points[number].g = green;
                cloud->points[number].b = blue;
                uint32_t rgb = (red << 16) | (green << 8) | (blue);
                cloud->points[number].rgb = rgb;
            }
            tokennumber++;
        }
        number++;
    }

    pcl::PolygonMesh mesh;
    pcl::toPCLPointCloud2(*cloud, mesh.cloud);
    pcl::io::saveOBJFile("C:\\Users\\ASUS\\Desktop\\out_color2.obj", mesh);
    cout << "文件保存完毕";`
```

but when I read the .obj file ， use loadPolygonFileOBJ()，I find the PointXYZRGB doesn't have rgb，it lost color

```
#include <string>
#include <pcl/io/io.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/io/obj_io.h>
#include <pcl/PolygonMesh.h>
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/io/vtk_lib_io.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/cloud_viewer.h>


using namespace pcl;
int main()
{
pcl::PolygonMesh mesh;
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
std::string s = "C:\\Users\\ASUS\\Desktop\\out_color2.obj";
pcl::io::loadPolygonFileOBJ(s, mesh);
pcl::fromPCLPointCloud2(mesh.cloud, *cloud);

    for (int i = 0; i < cloud->points.size(); i++) {
        PointXYZRGB point = cloud->points[i];
        cout << point.z << point.x << point.y<<endl;
        cout << point.r << point.g << point.b << endl;
    }

    boost::shared_ptr<visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer(new visualization::PCLVisualizer("3D viewer"));
    viewer->addPointCloud<PointXYZRGB>(cloud, "sample cloud");
    viewer->setBackgroundColor(255, 255, 255);
    while (!viewer->wasStopped()) {
        viewer->spinOnce(100);
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::microseconds(1000));
    }
 }
return 0;
}
```

before saveOBJFile(),the viewer.showCloud() can display color
but when saveOBJFile() and loadPolygonFileOBJ() after , the color lost
Is that .obj file contain color?
Or something wrong?
so how can I save the color then .obj file

Answer (score 0):

Generally .obj file is not suitable to hold colors. To use color in PCL, use ply file instead. Some other applications such as Meshlab on the other hand supports obj file with color.